# what is $apply & $digest functions in angularjs and its usage

Tags: angularjs

angular what is the difference between $apply & $digest functions
can anybody explain this exact usages of apply,digest functions & difference in angularjs and which scenario we can utilize these function

```
//digest function
$scope.$digest();

//apply function like this         
$scope.$apply(function(scope)
{
    scope.demo = "angular";
});
     (or)
//apply function like this
$scope.$apply(function()
{
    $scope.demo = "angular";
});
```

can anybody explain this exact usages of apply,digest functions & difference in angularjs and which scenario we can utilize these functions

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- `$scope.$digest()`: Runs a digest cycle on `$scope` and children.
- `$scope.$apply(expr)`: Evaluates `expr` and runs a digest cycle on `$rootScope`.

It is rarely advisable to call `$scope.$digest()` (unless you really know what you are doing), because it will not propagate changes outside to `$scope`'s subtree.

---

Very very briefly (because there are plenty of resources (post, tutorial etc) explaining the differences in depth):

---

```
$scope.$digest();
```

Starts a digest cycle on `$scope`, i.e. evaluates the watch-expressions of the watchers of `$scope` and its children and if necessary executes the watch-actions. This loop is repeated as many times as needed until all values stabilize (subject to the [digest ttl limit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider#digestTtl)).

---

```
$scope.$apply(expr);
```

Parses `expr` and evaluates it in the context of `$scope`. Then it invokes `$rootScope.$digest()`, which basically evaluates **all** watchers in the app (since every scope is a child of `$rootScope`).

Parsing `expr` (using `$parse`) results (more or less) in a function, which when called with a context as an argument (e.g. a scope) returns the result of evaluating `expr` in that context. Angular will call this function passing in `$scope` as the context.
If `expr` is already a function, there is no need to be actually parsed (again, this might be a little over-simplified, but applies to the majority of cases).
Another thing to note, is that executing code inside `$apply()` catches errors and passes then throught the `$exceptionHandler` (which is an added bonus).

Some examples:

```
// Let there be Scopes...
var scope1 = $rootScope.$new();
var scope2 = $rootScope.$new();
var scope2_1 = scope2.$new();

// Let there be watchers...
$rootScope.$watch(/* RootWatcher */);
scope1.$watch(/* Scope1Watcher */);
scope2.$watch(/* Scope2Watcher */);
scope2_1.$watch(/* Scope2_1Watcher */);

// Let there be `$digest`s...
$rootScope.$digest();   // Evaluates ALL watchers
scope1.$digest();       // Evaluates ONLY Scope1Watcher
scope2.$digest();       // Evaluates BOTH Scope2Watcher, Scope2_1Watcher
scope2_1.$digest();     // Evaluates ONLY Scope2_1Watcher

// Let there be `$apply`s...
$rootScope.$apply();          // Runs $rootScope.$digest()
scope1.$apply();              // Still runs $rootScope.$digest()
scope1.$apply('test = 42');   // Boils down to: scope1.test = 42
    // ...and is equivalent to:
    scope1.$apply(function (scope) { scope.test = 42; });
    // ...which in turn is equivalent to:
    scope1.$apply(function (ignored) { scope1.test = 42; });

// So, I could have a reusable function:
var assign42 = function (scope) { scope.test = 42; };
scope1.$apply(assign42);     // Boils down to: scope1.test = 42;
scope2.$apply(assign42);     // Boils down to: scope2.test = 42;
scope2_1.$apply(assign42);   // Boils down to: scope2_1.test = 42;
```

Another notable thing about `$apply()` is that is catches errors and passes them to Angular's [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) (which is a good thing). E.g.:

```
// BAD - Avoid doing this:
somePossiblyErrorThrowingFunc();
scope.$apply();

// GOOD - Do this instead:
scope.$apply(somePossiblyErrorThrowingFunc);
```

---

Needless to say, Angular (if used properly) will handle the digest lifecycle for you, so you don't have to call `$digest()`/`$apply()` manually.
Exceptions are event handlers bound to DOM elements and callbacks in third-party code that runs outside of the Angular context.
This is all pretty nicely explained in the docs as well: [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest), [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Answer (score 0):

That step that checks to see if any binding values have changed actually has a method, `$scope.$digest()`. That’s actually where the magic happens, but we almost never call it directly, instead we use `$scope.$apply()` which will call $scope.$digest() for you.

`$scope.$apply()` takes a function or an Angular expression string, and executes it, then calls `$scope.$digest()` to update any bindings or watchers.

So, when do you need to call $apply()?

Very rarely, actually. AngularJS actually calls almost all of your code within an $apply call. Events like `ng-click`, controller initialization, `$http` callbacks are all wrapped in `$scope.$apply()`. So you don’t need to call it yourself, in fact you can’t. Calling `$apply` inside $apply will throw an error.

You do need to use it if you are going to run code in a new turn. And only if that turn isn’t being created from a method in the AngularJS library. Inside that new turn, you should wrap your code in `$scope.$apply()`. Here is an example. We are using setTimeout, which will execute a function in a new turn after a delay. Since Angular doesn’t know about that new turn, the update will not be reflected.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### $digest()

- The `$scope.$digest()` function iterates through all the watches in the $scope object, and its child $scope objects (if it has any). When `$digest()` iterates over the watches, it calls the value function for each watch. If the value returned by the value function is different than the value it returned the last time it was called, the listener function for that watch is called.
- The `$digest()` function is called whenever `AngularJS` thinks it is necessary. For instance, after a button click handler has been executed, or after an AJAX call returns (after the done() / fail() callback function has been executed).
- You may encounter some corner cases where AngularJS does not call the $digest() function for you. You will usually detect that by noticing that the data bindings do not upate the displayed values. In that case, call $scope.$digest() and it should work. Or, you can perhaps use $scope.$apply() instead which I will explain in the next section.

---

### $apply()

- The `$scope.$apply()` function takes a function as parameter which is executed, and after that `$scope.$digest()` is called internally. That makes it easier for you to make sure that all watches are checked, and thus all data bindings refreshed. Here is an `$apply()` example:

  `$scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.data.myVar = "Another value";
  });`
- The function passed to the `$apply()` function as parameter will change the value of `$scope.data.myVar`. When the function exits `AngularJS` will call the `$scope.$digest() function so all watches are checked for changes in the watched values.

[Referred from](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

Comment: Nice answer, but kind or wrong :) `$scope.$apply()` does not necessarily need a function (e.g. it can get an Angular expression). Most importantly, `$scope.$apply()` call **`$rootScope.$digest()` (not `$scope.$digest()`), which can make a huge difference.